# Forward slash notation with Python dictionaries

Tags: python

I've never seen forward slash notation with Python dictionaries, and when looking to the official documentation, I couldn't find any reference, so I'm hoping someone can school me here.

I was playing with a new library I hope to use on a project when I ran across the notation:

object['/someKeyword']['/anotherKeyword'].someMethod()

I didn't understand what the bracketed terms meant at the time. A colleague helped me understand it was dictionary notation, but I haven't been able to find any follow up to study.

Any information on the notation would be helpful!

Comment: You can put any unicode character in *string*.

Comment: @heemayl Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are strings, and you can have any unicode codepoint as string constituting character, which obviously includes `/`.

In the example, it seems a `dict` like object is being accessed by subscription with string keys that start with `/`.

Comment: Of course... I feel silly now. What threw me off was that in this particular dictionary, every key was prefixed with a "/". It made me not recognize it was simply a nested dictionary.